# Error: Malformed UTF-8 data cryptojs in decryption

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, encryption, cryptojs

i got Malformed UTF-8 error while decrypt this encrypted data:

```
const str = `U2FsdGVkX18ZiW2uS4siFkyhfNNTONWKRZZ1O5PYI6CUqKcLJdv//7VxPVkwpV0L
rRz7javcch77rsCA5hcaJUNle1lxVRb3mWMHyogWpTLXdV6Oq10hstzcznwqHm4+
kgDZVXm/e6FX7JofiHH58gLVvYGSpNbCgSDcHzGzmqM+zye9QYFbLD8381zl3z88
b9p3MwwhjJZo6olXIMazcAkndbyAdgzfXJlGvs5whLeMgWtluSNnNKWkY26BfMwT
uLxvQQgzr8VjfjQ21a8cHXJEu2qrbuu0y2JkzxWvIwFLw9XjRFHn/rOlD+q1fSuO`;



const info2 = crypto.AES.decrypt(str , 'secret').toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
```

secret key is ok

[image]

i try these but not work yet

[My CryptoJS encryption/decryption is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574160/my-cryptojs-encryption-decryption-is-not-working)

[Why I get Malformed UTF-8 data error on crypto-js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111929/why-i-get-malformed-utf-8-data-error-on-crypto-js)

Comment: most likely the "secret" is wrong (despite you saying it's right)

Comment: @JaromandaX it is ok as i uploaded image at top,
it happens when encrypted data is morethan one line